# How to implement deserialisation in kafka consumer using scala?

Tags: scala, deserialization, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have the following line in my kafka consumer's code.

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicpMap).map(_._2)
```

How to deserialize this stream "lines" into original object? Serialisability was implemented in the kafka producer by extending class to serialisable. I am implementing this in spark using scala.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom [Decoder](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/serializer/Decoder.scala) and provide the expected type information together with the decoder to the createStream function.

`KafkaUtils.createStream[KeyType, ValueType, KeyDecoder, ValueDecoder] (...)`

For example, if you are using `String` as key and `CustomContainer` as value, your stream creation will look like this:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, CustomContainer, StringDecoder, CustomContainerDecoder](...)
```

Given that you are enconding the messages to kafka as `new KeyedMessage[String,String]`, the right decoder is a string decoder like this:

```
KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](topic,...)
```

that will give you a `DStream[String,String]` as basis for your processing.

If you want to send/receive a specific object type you need to implement a Kafka [Encoder](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/serializer/Encoder.scala) and [Decoder](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/serializer/Decoder.scala) for it.
Luckily for you, `PcapPacket` already implements the methods that you require to do that:

- PcapPacket -> byte[]: [public int transferStateAndDataTo(byte[] buffer)](http://sourceforge.net/p/jnetpcap/code/HEAD/tree/jnetpcap/releases/jnetpcap-1.3/release-1.3.0-1/src/java1.5/org/jnetpcap/packet/PcapPacket.java#l939)
- byte[] -> PcapPacket: [public PcapPacket(byte[] buffer)](http://sourceforge.net/p/jnetpcap/code/HEAD/tree/jnetpcap/releases/jnetpcap-1.3/release-1.3.0-1/src/java1.5/org/jnetpcap/packet/PcapPacket.java#l400)

The rest is boilerplate code to implement the Encoder/Decoder interfaces required by Kafka.

Comment: https://github.com/swe0523/producer/blob/master/producer.scala  This is the link to my producer code. Can you please help me?

Comment: @user3823859 see updated answer with feedback on your specific issue.

Comment: Thanks. After this is it possible to use stream.getCaptureHeader() like functionalities in kafka consumer which are available in jnetpcap library that is used in kafka producer?

Comment: No,  you're serializing the message as a String. You will have to parse the string to process the data.

Comment: Is there any built-in function to do the same?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question - the content of your capture is put into a string in the producer here: `new KeyedMessage[String,String](topic.toString,(packet).toString)`, specifically at `(packet).toString)`  You need to inspect that string and see if it contains the data you're looking for. If you want to access specifics of the `PcapPacket`, I suggest you extract that info at the producer side and put it in the string or a custom  serializable object.

Comment: I meant how is it possible to parse the string in consumer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62857/discussion-between-user3823859-and-maasg).

Comment: Is it then enough to write a Kafka Pcap encoder and decoder implementing the 2 methods?

Comment: @user3823859  why you don't try and ask additional questions in case it's needed?

Comment: By implementing the decoder byte[] -> PcapPacket: public int transferStateAndDataTo(byte[] buffer) , it returns int. But how to make it to PcapPacket format? I tried but it fails.

Comment: @user3823859 sorry, the methods were inversed int the answer. I've corrected that.

Comment: I tried implementing the encoder like this https://github.com/swe0523/producer/blob/master/Codec.scala  But it shows error: Implement abstract member toBytes(t:T):Array[Byte] in kafka.serializer.Encoder / Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PcapEncoder

Comment: @user3823859 please read the documentation: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/serializer/Encoder.scala

Comment: But this conversion using the methods you have specified don't work as conversion back to integer from array[byte] won't help us to access any functionalities of the library

Comment: @user3823859 I think you need to do your homework. These are the methods required; how to use them is just basic programming which is outside the scope of the question.