# Sending data from kafka producer in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

In this code:

```
import java.limport java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.util.Properties
import kafka.producer.{KeyedMessage, Producer, ProducerConfig}
import org.jnetpcap.Pcap
import org.jnetpcap.packet.{PcapPacket, PcapPacketHandler}

object kafkaproducer extends Serializable{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 4) {
      System.err.println("Usage: KafkaWordCountProducer <metadataBrokerList> <topic> " +
        "<messagesPerSec> <wordsPerMessage>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    //metadata.broker.list=localhost:9092
    //zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
    val Array(brokers, topic, messagesPerSec, wordsPerMessage) = args
    // Zookeeper connection properties
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers.toString)
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
    val config = new ProducerConfig(props)
    val producer = new Producer[String, PcapPacket](config)
    // Send some messages
    val snaplen = 64 * 1024 // Capture all packets, no truncation
    val flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS // capture all packets
    val timeout = 10 * 1000
    val jsb = new java.lang.StringBuilder()
    val errbuf = new StringBuilder(jsb);
    val pcap = Pcap.openLive("eth0", snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf)
    if (pcap == null) {
      println("Error : " + errbuf.toString())
    }

    while(true){

      val jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler[String]() {

        def nextPacket(packet: PcapPacket, user: String) {
          val data = new KeyedMessage[String,PcapPacket](topic.toString,(packet))
          println(data)
          producer.send(data)


        }
      }
      pcap.loop(50, jpacketHandler, "jNetPcap works!")


    }

  }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at kafka.serializer.StringEncoder.toBytes(Unknown Source)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(Unknown Source)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.serialize(Unknown Source)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Unknown Source)
at kafkaproducer$$anon$1.nextPacket(kafkaproducer.scala:50)
at kafkaproducer$$anon$1.nextPacket(kafkaproducer.scala:40)
at org.jnetpcap.Pcap.loop(Native Method)
at org.jnetpcap.Pcap.loop(Unknown Source)
at kafkaproducer$.main(kafkaproducer.scala:55)
at kafkaproducer.main(kafkaproducer.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Following error occured while sending data from kafka producer. In kafka producer, packets are captued using jnetpcap library. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you post the code as well?  You are probably trying to send an object of type PcapPacket using the StringSerializer

Comment: https://github.com/swe0523/producer/blob/master/producer.scala  Here is the link to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this exception is that the producer is configured to use a StringEncoder here:

```
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
```

Nevertheless, the actual value provided is of type `PcapPacket`. The producer will use the encoder to serialize the object and *boem* you have that class cast exception.

Also note that following the documentation of JNetPcap, you *may not* use the captured PcapPacket to transfer data. That object is mutable and will change in each capture with the newly captured data. [From the docs](http://jnetpcap.com/?q=node/68):

> Just like with JBufferHandler a single copy of PcapPacket is reused
>   for every packet from the same instance of the pcap dispatch loop. The
>   packet arrives fully decoded and can be accessed immediately, **but can
>   not be put away onto a queue or other permanent/semi-permanent
>   storage.** It needs to be either processed immediately by the user's
>   application, discarded or copied to more permanent memory location.

As I mentioned on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258553/how-to-implement-deserialisation-in-kafka-consumer-using-scala):

> If you want to access specifics of the PcapPacket, I suggest yIf you
>   want to access specifics of the PcapPacket, I suggest you extract that
>   info at the producer side and put it in the string or a custom
>   serializable object.

That's remains valid advice for this case.

Comment: Thank You. In the above link down the page, they say the packet can be put on a queue. So is it possible for me to put the same on kafka queue?

Comment: I've updated this question with pointer on how to implement your Encoder/Decoder functions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258553/how-to-implement-deserialisation-in-kafka-consumer-using-scala